Defining a variable based on two different variables with different weighting schemes in NHANES
I want to define a derived variable (Let's call it $Z$) using two original variables ($X$ and $Y$) in NHANES. If any of $X$ or $Y$ meets the criteria, the value for $Z$ should be 1; otherwise, it should be zero. I would consider $Z$ to equal 1 even if $X$ is missing, but $Y$ equals 1.
My issue is that the two variables are in different domains inside the examination piece of NHANES, such that $X$ requires using the WTMEC weights while $Y$ requires using specific weights for those who have undergone that test.
I initially thought I needed to use the smallest sample weights in weighting, which are related to $Y$. However, this will discard people who met the criteria based on $X$ being equal to 1. So, I am not sure what would be the best course of action in such situations.

The problem is people in the larger domain who have $X\neq 1$ but who would meet the criterion based on $Y$ if you had $Y$ available. You won't know who they are, but they will not have the correct value of your derived variable.
There seem to be two options

use just the sample with $Y$, which will be smaller but where you know the value of your derived variable for everyone
use the larger sample and accept that your derived variable will be wrong for some people

The choice between these will depend on other information: what proportion of people with your derived variable have $X=1$? how bad is it to miss out some people from the larger sample? how important is sample size? is it more important to get a population-representative set of people with $Z$ or a large set of people with $Z$?
I think the official-statistics approach would be to take the smaller sample where you really know the derived variable for everyone.
Another possibility is multiple imputation of $Z$, but that will only help if the people with $Z$ who don't have $X=1$ are predictable from other variables you do have.

Thank you so much for the response. I just want to emphasize that if $X \neq 1$ but $Y=1$, the derived variable $Z$ will be 1. In other words, I only need to know that at least either of $X$ or $Y$ equals 1. But if one of them is zero and the other one is NA, $Z$ would be NA. Would that change your perspective about the issue?
Regarding the second option, so you suggest to ignore the specific subsample weights and you use the WTMEC weights?

You can run this R code to get cross-grid view of the variables
structure(list(Z = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA), Y = c(0,  0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA), X = c(0, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA ), n = c(17880L, 6441L, 2710L, 3637L, 7695L, 15L, 30281L, 42L,  29136L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,  -9L))

In the second option: yes WTMEC. In the first option: that's my point. You have the correct definition of $Z$ for everyone where $Y$ is measured but you don't have it for everyone where $Y$ isn't  measured and there's no reason it would be a representative subsample

Sorry I mixed between $X$ and $Y$ in the previous code
Here is the correct one
Apologies I mixed $X$ and $Y$. Here is the correct code
structure(list(X = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA), Y = c(0,  1, NA, 0, 1, NA, 0, 1, NA), Z = c(0, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA ), n = c(17880L, 6441L, 30281L, 2710L, 3637L, 7695L, 42L, 15L,  29136L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",  "data.frame"))
